# Rigidbody with capsule collider moves on it's own *after* colliding with object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'll start this off by saying I am very new to Unity and C#, and I'm making my first solo project after following a tutorial series for Unity. I'm starting to make a first person shooter game, I have camera movement down, and I just wrote some code to handle player movement and acceleration. Initially when moving around a flat plane it works fine, but as soon as but as soon as my player object (PlayerColliderParent) bumps into a cube i have placed into the scene, it starts moving on its own at a constant speed and direction, depending on how it bumped into the cube. There aren't any other scripts that move PlayerColliderParent other than PlayerColliderParentScript.cs.

Here's a video of the problem occuring
[why is it moving???](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QuOoO.gif)

Here is PlayerColliderParentScript.cs (attached to PlayerColliderParent)

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerColliderParentScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform cameraRotation;
    public Vector3 directionalInput;
    public float accelerationFactor = 0.1f;
    public float maxSpeed = 6f;
    public Vector3 directionalSpeed;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
       
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        //rotate horizontally with camera
        transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(0, cameraRotation.localEulerAngles.y, 0);

    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        //accelerate while movement key is held
        //z axis
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
        {
            directionalInput.z = 1;
            if (directionalSpeed.z < maxSpeed)
            {
                directionalSpeed.z += accelerationFactor;
            }
        }
        else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S))
        {
            directionalInput.z = -1;
            if (directionalSpeed.z < maxSpeed)
            {
                directionalSpeed.z += accelerationFactor;
            }
        }
        else if (directionalSpeed.z > 0)
        {
            directionalInput.z = 0;
            directionalSpeed.z -= accelerationFactor;
        }
        else if (directionalSpeed.z < 0)
        {
            directionalInput.z = 0;
            directionalSpeed.z += accelerationFactor;
        }
        else
        {
            directionalInput.z = 0;
        }

        //x axis
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
        {
            directionalInput.x = 1;
            if (directionalSpeed.x < maxSpeed)
            {
                directionalSpeed.x += accelerationFactor;
            }
        }
        else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
        {
            directionalInput.x = -1;
            if (directionalSpeed.x < maxSpeed)
            {
                directionalSpeed.x += accelerationFactor;
            }
        }
        else if (directionalSpeed.x > 0)
        {
            directionalInput.x = 0;
            directionalSpeed.x -= accelerationFactor;
        }
        else if (directionalSpeed.x < 0)
        {
            directionalInput.x = 0;
            directionalSpeed.x += accelerationFactor;
        }
        else
        {
            directionalInput.x = 0;
        }

        //move the player according to directional speed
        Vector3 direction = directionalInput.normalized * Time.deltaTime;
        float velocityX = direction.x * directionalSpeed.x;
        float velocityY = direction.y * directionalSpeed.y;
        float velocityZ = direction.z * directionalSpeed.z;
        Vector3 velocity = new Vector3(velocityX, velocityY, velocityZ);
        transform.Translate(velocity);
    }


}
```

Comment: Does the `PlayerColliderParent` have a Rigidbody?

Comment: If `PlayerColliderParent` does have a rigidbody, what is it's gravity and friction settings?

Comment: @derHugo - Yes, it does

Comment: @DekuDesu not sure what gravity and friction settings you're reffering to, but it has a mass of 1, drag od 0, and angular drag of 0.05

Answer (score 3):

Make sure to make the `Rigidbody` have [`isKinematic`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-isKinematic.html) **enabled**. This way you can control it in `FixedUpdate` via the `transform.Translate` and it won't react to **any** Physics while the collision detection is still intact.

---

Otherwise in general whenever you have a `Rigidbody` you don't have want to set values via the `Transform` component.

I'm pretty sure what happens is that after you are already moving, the `Rigidbody` has a certain `velocity`. You are never again changing that velocity so after a collision you have both, the user Input applied via `Transform` and the `Rigidbody`'s own [`velocity`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-velocity.html).

Instead of using `transform.Translate` rather directly manipulate the `Rigidbody.velocity` itself.

```
[SerializeField] Rigidbody _rigidbody;

...

    //accelerate while movement key is held
    //z axis
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
    {
        directionalInput.z = 1;
        directionalSpeed.z += accelerationFactor * Time.deltaTime;
    }
    else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S))
    {
        directionalInput.z = -1;
        directionalSpeed.z -= accelerationFactor * Time.deltaTime;
    }
    else
    {
        directionalInput.z = 0;

        if (directionalSpeed.z > 0)
        {
            directionalSpeed.z -= accelerationFactor * Time.deltaTime;
        }
        else if (directionalSpeed.z < 0)
        {
            directionalSpeed.z += accelerationFactor * Time.deltaTime;
        }
    }

    directionalSpeed.z = Mathf.Clamp(directionalSpeed.z, -maxSpeed, maxSpeed);

    //x axis
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
    {
        directionalInput.x = 1;
        directionalSpeed.x += accelerationFactor * Time.deltaTime;
    }
    else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
    {
        directionalInput.x = -1;
        directionalSpeed.x -= accelerationFactor * Time.deltaTime;
    }
    else
    {
        directionalInput.x = 0;

        if (directionalSpeed.x > 0)
        {
            directionalSpeed.x -= accelerationFactor * Time.deltaTime;
        }
        else if (directionalSpeed.x < 0)
        {
            directionalSpeed.x += accelerationFactor * Time.deltaTime;
        }
    }

    directionalSpeed.x = Mathf.Clamp(directionalSpeed.x, -maxSpeed, maxSpeed);

    _rigidbody.velocity = directionalInput;
```

---

As mentioned by @Rhach also the rotation is an issue.

You should probably rather use e.g.

```
_rigidbody.MoveRotation(new Vector3(0, cameraRotation.localEulerAngles.y, 0));
```

Comment: This seems the most probable thing that could be going wrong, so I won't make another answer. Another thing to check is the pivot point of the player, since he is changing the rotation in Update without any constrains or checks.

Comment: @Rhach yes you're right that is most probably an additional issue!

Comment: Thank you, changing to rigidbody velocity worked :)